# Multiple File Upload with Metadata Using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

I want to upload multiple file with metadata using REST service. I am using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086(v=office.15).aspx it works perfectly fine with single file upload for multiple file upload it does not work.

Can anyone help with this? I am using office 365 tenant.

Comment: Use below link for further reference:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185566/upload-multiple-files-with-rest-api-in-document-library-with-custom-properties

Answer (score 2):

The REST api does not provide for uploading multiple files in a single call. You would need to write your javascript to loop thru the collection of files and issue individual calls.

Scot Hillier has a post which contains utility functions to do most of the work: http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/03/26/uploading-files-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom-and-rest.aspx