# Upload multiple files with REST API in document library with custom properties

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, api

I am trying to upload multiple documents to the document library, I followed the answer posted on this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154472/upload-multiple-files-using-rest-api), I am able to upload the documents but I have some custom columns in the library, please help me on uploading the documents with custom properties. For e.g. I am uploading documents for a task/project and I want to associate task id/Project id to this document under custom properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For updating custom column while uploading file you use following code with [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154472/upload-multiple-files-using-rest-api/187910#187910)

```
function upload() {
    // Define the folder path for this example.
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'SiteAssets';

    // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();
    var fileCount = fileInput[0].files.length;
    // Get the server URL.
    var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var filesUploaded = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
        // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        var getFile = getFileBuffer(i);
        getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer, i) {

            // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
            var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, i);
            addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
               //Get ID of File uploaded 
                var getfileID = getItem(file.d);
                getfileID.done(function (fResult) {
                    var colObject = new Object();
                    colObject["FileType"] = fileType;
                    var changeItem = updateFileMetadata(libraryName, fResult.d, colObject);
                    changeItem.done(function (result) {
                        filesUploaded++;
                        if (fileCount == filesUploaded) {
                            alert("All files uploaded successfully");
                            //$("#msg").append("<div>All files uploaded successfully</div>");
                            $("#getFile").value = null;
                            filesUploaded = 0;
                        }
                    });
                    changeItem.fail(function (result) {

                    });

                }, function () { });

            });
            addFile.fail(onError);
        });
        getFile.fail(onError);

    }

    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer(i) {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result, i);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[i]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, i) {
        var index = i;

        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var fileName = fileInput[0].files[index].name;

        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
    }
}

// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}

function updateFileMetadata(libraryName, item, colPropObject) {
    var def = jQuery.Deferred();

    var restSource = siteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('" + libraryName + "')/Items(" + item.Id + ")";
    var jsonString = "";

    var metadataColumn = new Object();
    metadataColumn["type"] = item.__metadata.type;
    //columnArray.push(metadataColumn);
    if (colPropObject == null || colPropObject == 'undefined')// For library having no column properties to be updated
    {
        colPropObject = new Object();
    }
    colPropObject["__metadata"] = metadataColumn;
    jsonString = JSON.stringify(colPropObject);
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        'url': restSource,
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': jsonString,
        'headers':
            {
                'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'X-RequestDigest': jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                "IF-MATCH": item.__metadata.etag,
                "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"
            },
        'success': function (data) {
            var d = data;
            dfd.resolve(d);
        },
        'error': function (err) {
            dfd.reject(err);
        }
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
/*=====================================================
Get Item for Uploaded Document
=======================================================*/
function getItem(file) {
    var def = jQuery.Deferred();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: file.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            def.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (data, arg, jhr) {
            def.reject(data, arg, jhr);
        }
    });
    return def.promise();
    //return call;
}
```