# Get URL of document in document library and show it in other column of same record

Tags: ootb

I have a library in which I store .doc files. I want to show URL of document in another column (say. DocumentURL).

The library should show URL of the document in DocumentURL column when new document is added to library

Please suggest ootb procedure.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with an workflow (below with an SharePoint 2010 WF) and "Set Field in Current Item". So the field would be "DocumentURL" and the value ist over "Workflow Context" available.

The column could be an "Hyperlink or Picture" column.

1. Workflow Action

   [image]
2. Properties of the action

   [image]
3. If you want to start the workflow after uploading make sure the start options are set

   [image]
4. The output should be similar to this

   [image]

If you click on that link, it will open up the .pdf file and you can also copy that link and send it via e-mail.

Comment: but on clicking this URL I get display form of the record. I want a visible link to open the document to which I copy and paste (i.e the link) and send to someone via email...

Comment: updated answer. For me it is working, maybe you can update your question with an screenshot?

Comment: Any news @Lucifer? Does my answer work for you?

Comment: thanks Patrick. [Current Item:Encoded Item URL] worked for me.

Comment: allright, you may consider to rate my answer as "the answer" so others could find a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to go workflow you can refer the below [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185566/upload-multiple-files-with-rest-api-in-document-library-with-custom-properties/187965#187965) for get all metadata of doc's

Answer (score 0):

Please try the CSR below:

```
function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        Templates: {
            Fields: {
                "DocumentURL": {
                    View: function(ctx) {
                        return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + ctx.CurrentItem["FileRef"];
                    },
                }
            },
        },
        ListTemplateType: 101
    });
}
RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/DocURL.js"), init);
init();
```

You might have to change the column name ('DocumentURL') to the internal name of the corresponding column in your list.

You might have to change the URL in the RegisterModuleInit-function depending on where you upload the script and how you call the file.