# How do i get document link uploaded to a document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

i have excel/word files in a document library. when i click on it , it opens directly on the browser. i need to get the link with the name in the end.

For example i need the url to be as below
https://he.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/PMCM/SiteAssets/ppm%20forms/CHANGE%20CONTROL.docx

do i have to manually create the url as above or is there a way i can extract the information from SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view contains the column `Name (linked to document with edit menu)` then there will be 3 little dots right next to the filename. When you click on it you will find a field containing the document URL.

Alternatively you could create an additional column and use the JSLink CSR from [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190042/get-url-of-document-in-document-library-and-show-it-in-other-column-of-same-reco/190053#190053) to display the documents URL in the column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this by coding side (SPService/JSOM), then **FileRef** attribute will return the document URl and **FileLeafRef** attribute will return the document Name, so finally to get the absolute URL you have to append it with Root site URL, like below in your case
//JSOM Example
var docUrl = oItem.get_item('FileRef');
var docName = oItem.get_item('FileLeafRef');

('https://he.sharepoint.com' + docUrl) will give you the complete url of the document