# Sharepoint 2010: Upload multiple files in Shared Documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, file-upload, user-controls

I would like to upload multiple files in Sharepoint "Shared Documents" with user control 
this is my ascx :

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fileBrowse" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Files" OnClick="fileUpload_Click" />
```

and my code behind :

```
  protected void fileUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileBrowse.HasFile)
        {
            string filename = fileBrowse.PostedFile.FileName;
          //  string allpath = Path.GetFileName(fileBrowse.PostedFile.FileName);
         //   string all = Path.GetFullPath(fileBrowse.PostedFile.FileName);
            String fileToUpload = @filename;
            String sharePointSite = "http://.../sites/GM/";
            String documentLibraryName = "Shared Documents";

            using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);

                    SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

                    // Prepare to upload
                    Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                    String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
                    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

                    // Upload document
                    SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

                    // Commit 
                    myLibrary.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it just upload 1 file, and it works in dev machine, not client machine "File not found"

Help please

Comment: You can refer my code on the below [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185566/upload-multiple-files-with-rest-api-in-document-library-with-custom-properties/187965#187965)

Comment: @Sunilsahu, could you please help me to understand why it's not working ?

Comment: you have to allow multiple files on fileupload control and loop through the files users selected..... this is supported in .net 4.0...else you need to have multiple file upload control with your button control click reading each file upload controls and uploading to sharepoint...

Answer (score 0):

Please add AllowMultiple="true" in your file uploader control

And in code use

```
if (fileBrowse.HasFiles)
{
foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in fileBrowse.PostedFiles)
   {
 /// your code for file upload.
   }
}
```

Comment: Sunil sahu, I will try it now

Comment: but could you please , explain to me . why in the dev machine to load 1 file, it works , but in the local machine, it said file not found for the same user ?

Comment: error message :foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' because 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Are you using update panel

Comment: no I m not. I m putting my controls in a div,

Comment: Not sure but check the browser