# Multiple File Upload in dialog box

Tags: file-upload, library, modal-dialog, online

I have custom button which opens a dialog box of out of the box page `Upload.aspx` of a document library.

First I am getting the `GUID` of the library by REST API and then passing the URL to open it into the dialog.

Below is my code to open the dialog box by button click:

```
var openDialog = function(pageUrl) { 
    var options = {
        url: pageUrl,
        title: 'Upload Document to Upload Library',
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 300
    };
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);       
}

var GenerateButtonURL = function(listTitle){
    try {
        var currWebURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:  currWebURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')?$select=Id",
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                openDialog(currWebURL + '/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={' + data.d.Id + '}&RootFolder=');
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.error("Error: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
    }
}
```

The code works properly. it allow user to upload a file and it is saved to actual document library.

But my problem is when I try to select multiple file, it doesn't allow me, where the actual out of the page when I click upload from the document library it allows the multiple file upload.

I have verified both the pages have the same URL. I have tried doing it with static GUID but still no luck.

What am I missing here? Anyone have encountered such issue before?

**Edit:**

Found that if page is opened from the out of the box library page UI Looks as below, button text for upload is **Choose Files**:

[image]

When I open the same page with custom code, it shows below screen, button text for upload is **Choose File**.

[image]

Comment: you can try to replicate the uploadex.aspx functionality , that's available in 15\template\layouts\ folder. By default sharepoint doesn't allow multiple file upload.

Comment: you can create a custom upload page for your requirement and this custom page inherits Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.UploadExPage class.
Refer the below link for more info:
http://byteloom.marek-mierzwa.com/2012/01/20/custom-upload-form-for-document-library.html

Comment: Thank you for your response @SaMolPP, but I cannot replicate this functionality as I have no option available to build the WSP.

Comment: I have found one more useful link : But here also, C# is required to build httphandler.                                 https://spbreed.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/sharepoint-multi-file-upload-control-with-metadata-using-uploadify-and-httphandler/

Answer (score 3):

The REST api does not provide for uploading multiple files in a single call. You would need to write your javascript to loop thru the collection of files and issue individual calls. 
Refer this one : [Upload multiple files with REST API in document library with custom properties](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185566/upload-multiple-files-with-rest-api-in-document-library-with-custom-properties)

Comment: Appreciate you answer but I am not trying to achieve this with REST, I am just trying to use out of the box page which is `_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={59186CEC-D2B9-47C3-A2C3-EBCA2C4E2F1A}&RootFolder=&IsDlg=1`  so the file upload will be handled by out of the page itself. Only thing is when I use above code, multiple file upload doesn't work.

Comment: Multiple upload not allowed with out of the box functionality, you can try with this, /_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={' + data.d.Id + '}&MutipleUpload=1&RootFolder=' will give an error "Multiple upload not allowed"

Comment: If I try this approach, it allows only one file to select, it is not giving any error like you mentioned. Does that mean what I am trying to achieve is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible when calling the upload.aspx from a custom form. You can set the upload.aspx page to allow the selection of multiple files using this:

```
$("[id$='InputFile']").attr("multiple", "true");
```

...and it looks like it will work. It allows you to select more than one file and it displays everything you selected, but it only uploads the first file.

I compared the onclick event of the OK button when called from the library and when called from my custom script and it's different.  I tried to mimic the original and it runs without error, but it only uploads the first document.

There must be something under the code that ignores the additional ones but I haven't been able to find it yet.